# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column when submitting form with subfield relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

This issue happens for me on Backpack v5 and Laravel 8 (although I do reproduce it on Laravel 9 as well).

My issue happens when I have a setup similar to this one : https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-fields#manage-related-entries-in-the-same-form-create-update-delete

Just to clarify here:

- Two models related by a 1-n relationship
- Those models override their `$primaryKey` attribute (as their primary key is not "id")
- the "parent" models CRUD that has a `'type' => 'relationship'` with `'subfields'` to add children through a "repeatable" type field

This is the error I get (with the Monsters and Stories example):

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id_story' in 'where clause' 

select * from `monsters` where `monsters`.`story_id` = 5 and `monsters`.`story_id` is not null and (`id_story` is null) limit 1
```

The stack trace leads me to `vendor\backpack\crud\src\app\Library\CrudPanel\Traits\Create.php:310`

Here is how I reproduced it on the Backpack demo projet:

- Install demo project following instructions here :https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/demo#demo-installation
- Rename `monsters` primary key in table to `id_monster` and `stories` primary key to `id_story`
- Add the `$primaryKey` overrides on corresponding models like so:

  ```
   protected $primaryKey = 'id_monster'; // In Monster.php
   protected $primaryKey = 'id_story'; // In Story.php
  ```
- Add correct "foreignKey" parameters to relation method like so:

  ```
    // In Story.php
    public function monsters()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Monster::class, 'story_id');
    }

    // In Monster.php
    public function story()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Story::class, 'story_id');
    }
  ```

Now add a story with a monster through the Crud panel and you should reproduce the error.

I'm thinking I'm probably missing something but I just can't figure it out. I'm pretty sure the relations are properly defined and I'm wondering if it's not a bug in Backpack.

Thanks for your help !

**UPDATE**

This is indeed an issue that has been reported [here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/4384)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you are using "story_id" in both relations (Story.php and Monster.php).

In Story.php you should use :

```
  public function monsters()
  {
     return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Monster::class, 'story_id');
  }
```

And In Monster.php you should use :

```
  public function story()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Story::class, 'monster_id');
  }
```

Also be careful that when you are trying to set relationships in migrations and in models, you are setting correct foreign keys both in migration and models.

Comment: And yeah thanks for pointing out the migrations indeed I just put out this example as a fast way to reproduce, but I can confirm that the tables have the correct column names

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't solve the issue. Furthermore, are you sure that 'monster_id' is the correct foreignKey in the story() relation of Monster.php ? I'm pretty sure it should be story_id, since we are referencing the foreignKey in the monsters table right ? In this exemple, there IS no monster_id column since it's a 1-n relation